# Laravel attach() error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Recipe` model, with a relationship to `Category` model (recipe can be in multiple categories).

This is how my relationship code in my recipe model:

```
public function categories()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
        }
```

And here I'm trying to attach it:

```
$recipe = new Recipe;
$recipe->title = $request->recipe['title'];
$recipe->categories()->attach($request->categories);
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()"

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attach()` method is only for `many-to-many` relationship and can't be used for the one many relationship.

You are using attach method for the one to many relationship between `Receipe` and `Category`.

you can see docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)